# $2\times2$ Lower triangular matrices form a subspace of $R^{2x2}$

Tags: vector-spaces, solution-verification

"Let $H \subset \Bbb{R^{2x2}}$ be the set of lower-triangular matrices. Show that $H$ is a subspace of the vector space $\Bbb{R^{2x2}}$."

Proof. Clearly $H\neq \emptyset$. For example $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\ 1&1\end{bmatrix}\in H$

Let $A,B \in H$. Both of them are lower triangular and identical in size. Hence $A+B$ is defined. Let $[a_1 a_2]$ and $[b_1 b_2]$ denote the columns of $A$ and $B$. $$A+B=[(a_1+b_1) (a_2 + b_2)]$$

Because $A$ and $B$ are lower triangular, it is clear that the first term of column $a_1+b_2$ is $0+0=0$.  This means $A+B$ is lower triangular.  Thus for all $A,$ and $B$ we have that $ A+B \in H$.

Let $c\in \Bbb{R}$.  Now $cA=[(ca_1) (ca_2)]$. Again, the first term of column $ca_1$ is $c\cdot 0$ and $cA \in H$ for all scalars $c$. There is a follow up question : "Is $H$ a subspace if its elements are also invertible?" I don't really get what this means. Surely the proof is just the same even if $A,B$ are invertible?

Comment: minor typos: should be "first term of column $a_2+b_2$" and "first term of column $ca_2$".

Comment: The last question is asking "if $H$ is the set of invertible lower-triangular $2 \times 2$ matrices, is it a subspace"?

Comment: Yes I understood that much. I still can't understand how that fundamentally changes the proof.

Comment: If $A$ is lower triangular invertible, then $A - A$ is no longer invertible.

Comment: Oh yes, then the result wont be in $H$ anymore.